# Arithmetic overflow when trying to take an average

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am getting the following error when trying to execute a query

> Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric

I have narrowed the issue down to the included code. My problem is I am unsure of how to handle the overflow error. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
avg(cast((Substring([Ice].Entry(5, UD03.Character01,';'),0,
CharIndex('|',[Ice].Entry(5, UD03.Character01,';'))))
as decimal(38,38))) as [Calculated_Markup]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `try_cast()` or `try_convert()`:

```
avg(try_convert(decimal(38, 38),
                Substring([Ice].Entry(5, UD03.Character01,';'), 1,
                          CharIndex('|', [Ice].Entry(5, UD03.Character01, ';')))) as [Calculated_Markup]
```

Note:  I changed the `0` to a `1` because substring processing starts at 1.  You can write this more succinctly using `LEFT()`:

```
avg(try_convert(decimal(38, 38),
                left([Ice].Entry(5, UD03.Character01,';'),
                     CharIndex('|', [Ice].Entry(5, UD03.Character01, ';')))) as [Calculated_Markup]
```

Note:  This fixes the error by using `NULL` if the convert fails.

I will note that `decimal(38, 38)` is a trifle unusual -- that is a number that has only 38 digits after the decimal.  Often there are more digits before the decimal, so I would expect something more like `decimal(38, 15)`.  That would be 15 digits after and 23 before.

Comment: Thank you, the code worked as you described but the real issue was the note you provided, thank you.